# Separate GCS terraform backends to deploy multiple resources in respective projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-state

I have three GCP projects let's say `project-01`, `project-02` and `project-03` and I'm trying to create Compute Instance in those respective projects using single terraform module. Below is the `terraform.tfvars` file

```
compute_instances = {
  compute_instance_01 = {
    project_id                   = "project-01"
    instance_name                = "instance_01"
    zone                         = "asia-south1-a"
    machine_type                 = "e2-small"
  }

  compute_instance_02 = {
    project_id                   = "project-02"
    instance_name                = "instance_02"
    zone                         = "asia-south1-a"
    machine_type                 = "e2-medium"
  }

  compute_instance_03 = {
    project_id                   = "project-03"
    instance_name                = "instance_03"
    zone                         = "asia-south1-a"
    machine_type                 = "e2-large"
  }
 }
```

How do I keep terraform state file in remote GCS bucket in their respective projects in single `backends.tf` file ?

Comment: The below mentioned links will be useful to you.Let me know in case of any queries. (1) https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/store-state (2) https://www.jorgebernhardt.com/terraform-backend-gcp/

Comment: @KiranKotturi I know how to store state file in remote bucket, but I need to understand how to write single `backend.tf` file for each backends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly what you would like to achieve ultimately, and I guess it might not be possible to get that 100% accurately, but something can be done.

From the best of my understanding, one can define a Terraform state file location running the `terraform init` command.

For example:

```
        terraform init \
        -backend-config=bucket="<<gcs bucket name>>" \
        -backend-config=prefix="<<a path prefix inside the bucket>>"
```

Under assumption, that the `backend.tf` file looks like:

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
  }
}
```

So, while it might not be possible to create many terraform state files from one `terraform init/apply` command set, it may be possible to

- choose what is to be deployed and what is not (deployed) in one or another terraform execution, or probably better to
- define names of resources (including identifiers of the target projects for deployment, names of resources to be deployed, and target buckets/prefixes for the terraform state files storage) in some variables (in bash outside of the terraform files and/or inside terraform files), so when the `init` is executed, the correct state file location is chosen; and when the `apply` is executed, the correct resource names are calculated.

Let me know if you would like further hints on how to achieve the later, or the above information is enough.